# Best practice to get data from Asyncstorage database in react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I have tried to get data from database using Asyncstorage .in the way like below.

```
async () => {
    var x;
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('DB', (err, result) => {
      x = result; // I'm getting the data here
    });

    return JSON.parse(x);// this statement gets executed before I get values from result to x 
  },
```

My questions are as follows 
1) where should the code be placed (in componentDidMount or constructor)
2) how should I get values into this.state.dataList

Since in .then of promise returns another promise I'm not able to get values in this.state.dataList

Answer (score 1):

When you `await` something, you're awaiting on the Promise to resolve to a value. You're kind of mixing the old way of doing something (callbacks) and the new way (Promises/async-await)

`const x = await AsyncStorage.getItem('DB')`

edit: I see that there is an optional callback - but even in the docs they recommend just awaiting/resolving the value via the Promise chain

To answer your questions,

1. because you're setting state, it should be placed in `componentDidMount`
2. `AsyncStorage.getItem('DB').then((result) => this.setState({ dataList: result })`

Comment: you cannot just use await wihout an async function